# Обработка нескольких полученных значений из подзапроса

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT position_name 
FROM store_assortment 
WHERE id = (SELECT position_id FROM content WHERE order_id = 9)
```

Подзапрос возвращает больше одного значения. Как сделать, чтобы основная часть запроса последовательно выполнилась для каждого из полученных значений?

Как переписать запрос, чтобы он выполнился именно для каждого значения из подзапроса? Грубо говоря, как циклично подставлять значения из подзапроса в запрос?

Comment: Перепешите с EXISTS

Comment: Замените `=` на `IN` или используйте `JOIN`.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis а как мне это поможет? мне нужно выполнить запрос для каждого значения из подзапроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT position_name 
FROM store_assortment st
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM content WHERE order_id = 9 AND position_id = st.id)
```

Или

```
SELECT position_name 
FROM store_assortment
WHERE id IN (SELECT position_id FROM content WHERE order_id = 9)
```